# Play or Download an Audio file

Tags: files

I'm running a radio website on Drupal 7 http://punkrockradio.net/
We have podcast that user can listen with Pushtape Player using  Soundmanager2 API.
I have installed DownloadFile.

I would like to give my user the option to listen to the file or to download it.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could accomplish this. Some might be better than others depending on your specific requirements.

Since [soundmanager2](https://www.drupal.org/project/soundmanager2) and [downloadfile](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file) both provide field formatters the easiest way is probably just to print the field twice, each with a different formatter.

A couple of ways you might do that (this is not an exhaustive list) are:

- Create a node view with a contextual filter that takes a node ID. Set the filter to use a default value if no value is present and set the default to be the node ID from URL. Then put the field in question in the view twice with the different formatters. Then either [manually print the view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/14103/10729) in your node template or use the [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module to show the view on the node.
- Set the field up to display as one of the formatters via the node display settings UI and [print it manually](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/30063/10729) in the node template like you would any other field. Then also add a [node preprocess function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/72812/10729) to render the field a second time with the other formatter into a custom variable using [field_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7). Then print that custom field rendering alongside the other field rendering.

I can possibly provide more detail on those solutions if you have further questions.

Comment: just to add another option,jplayer(https://www.drupal.org/project/jplayer) can also be helpful here like soundmanager2.